# Jquery Event Trigger Keyboard Simulation

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, keyboard

i'm doing a minimal example [http://jsfiddle.net/*PSYCKIC*/SQZVH/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/SQZVH/1/)

Can't not put it work, but the idea is to simulate a keyboard event as keypress,keydown or keyup that works for every browser(Firefox, Safari, Chrome , IE).

Not sure why the code isn't working, any ideia how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the current solution working for Chrome and Firefox, still need to check if work Opera and IE

```js
// put cursor and input text in correct position

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
    if (elem != null) {
        if (elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {

            if (elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
                elem.focus();

                // Workaround for FireFox overflow no scroll problem
                if ($.browser.mozilla) {

                    // Trigger a "space" keypress.
                    var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
                    evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, 32);
                    elem.dispatchEvent(evt);

                }
                // for webkit 
                if ($.browser.webkit || $.browser.msie) {
                    var te = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
                    // Trigger a "space" keypress.
                    te.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, window, ' ');
                    elem.dispatchEvent(te);
                }

            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even being the correct answer , not sure the Opera or Ie Working.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#test").trigger(event.type);
```

Comment: Did you test ? For me not working, I'm using firefox 3.6 in a Mac OS. Not sure if could that be the problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acheive? The event fires but if you haven't bound an event to the input you're not going to see much.

Comment: [updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/SQZVH/2/) contains an event bount to the input that then gets called when the event you have created is triggered.

Comment: I would like to put the event.keyCode = 65; (Character "a") inside the input.


Like this solution, unfortunately it only works for firefox: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686053/keeping-caret-position-in-a-visible-position-in-text-input-firefox-misbehaves

Comment: Thanks, is working that example..probably my explanation wasn't so good.