# How to simulate keypress in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How would I go about simulating a keypress within my editable iframe? (Same domain.)

The iframe has designmode on, and the body is being used as a text field for an RTE.

I have a feeling I need to use the trigger function from jquery, but  I am unable to get it to work.

```
$('#editor body').trigger({type: 'keypress', which: 13, keyCode: 13});
```

EDIT: Apparently this isn't possible. Is there any way to make an iframe scroll to the cursor's position without pressing a key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688268/can-a-button-click-cause-an-event-in-iframe/24689865#24689865

Comment: Guest, thats pretty much perfect. Does it work for iframes in the HTML code or does the iframe have to be added via jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with events. Events don't cause keypresses. Keypresses cause events.

WYSIWYG editors [have an API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Midas) that you can use to [interact](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html) with the editor.

---

However, if you really need to fire events, then the problem can be broken down into two that already have answers:

- [how to fire an event in a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript/2490876#2490876)
- [how to access document of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Oh. I thought it was possibly to simulate an event using jquery. 

Is there any way to mimic an arrow key after running a function? (Move the caret over 1 position).

Comment: When searching for ways to have the area scroll to the caret I was given solutions such as this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686053/keeping-caret-position-in-a-visible-position-in-text-input-firefox-misbehaves
which tells the user to fake a keypress. I have already created a custom editor (Which works great with the only bug being scrolling and undo) so I wish to keep using it rather than swap to a different editor. Is there a more valid way to achieve the scroll?