# Keydown Simulation in Chrome fires normally but not the correct key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I want to simulate `keydown` events on a given textarea element in an html page. Since I am using Chrome, I called `initKeyboardEvent` on my variable and I passed the `keyCode` I want to type into the textarea. Here is what I tried:

```
var keyEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
keyEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, false, null, 0, false, 0, false, 77, 0);
inputNode.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

In this code I'm typing the letter <kbd>m</kbd> however the textarea is only getting the `keyCode` 13 which is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. So, I tried an override code I saw online that sets the value to `keyCodeVal`, but with no success.

```
var keyEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
Object.defineProperty(keyEvent, 'keyCode', { 
                         get : function() {
                                 return this.keyCodeVal;
                         }
                        });
keyEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, false, null, 0, false, 0, false, 77, 0);
keyEvent.keyCodeVal = 77;
inputNode.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to set the `keyCode` value?

Comment: **EDITED**: Orwellophile's solution does work. Check out this demo to see it in action + a generic event alternative : http://jsbin.com/awenaq/4

Comment: Note: manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 80, accepted):

So very very close...

You just needed to override the 'which' property.  Here's some sample code:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => console.log(
'altKey                : ' + e.altKey + '\n' +
'charCode (Deprecated) : ' + e.charCode + '\n' +
'code                  : ' + e.code + '\n' +
'ctrlKey               : ' + e.ctrlKey + '\n' +
'isComposing           : ' + e.isComposing + '\n' +
'key                   : ' + e.key + '\n' +
'keyCode (Deprecated)  : ' + e.keyCode + '\n' +
'location              : ' + e.location + '\n' +
'metaKey               : ' + e.metaKey + '\n' +
'repeat                : ' + e.repeat + '\n' +
'shiftKey              : ' + e.shiftKey + '\n' +
'which (Deprecated)    : ' + e.which + '\n' +
'isTrusted             : ' + e.isTrusted + '\n' +
'type                  : ' + e.type
));

Podium = {};
Podium.keydown = function(k) {
  var oEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

  // Chromium Hack
  Object.defineProperty(
    oEvent,
    'keyCode',
    {
       get : function() {
         return this.keyCodeVal;
       }
    }
  );
  Object.defineProperty(
    oEvent,
    'which',
    {
       get : function() {
         return this.keyCodeVal;
       }
    }
  );

  if (oEvent.initKeyboardEvent) {
    oEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView,
                             false, false, false, false, k, k);
  }
  else {
      oEvent.initKeyEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView,
                          false, false, false, false, k, 0);
  }

  oEvent.keyCodeVal = k;

  if (oEvent.keyCode !== k) {
    alert("keyCode mismatch " + oEvent.keyCode + "(" + oEvent.which + ")");
  }

  document.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
}

//Sample usage
Podium.keydown(65);
```

Note: this code is not designed to work in IE, Safari, or other browsers.  Well, maybe with Firefox.  YMMV.

Comment: I used this in a Chrome extension to trigger a keydown event on a textarea (on Facebook). For some reason the site's handler is never fired, so it doesn't seem to respond. Any idea why?

Comment: It works fine for me, Version 21.0.1180.89. Note depressed key in virtual keyboard - http://nt4.com/ss/keydown-65.png. Perhaps you misunderstand exactly what it's doing.  Whilst I appreciate your concerns, they are outside the scope of the original question.  @sunglim:thanks for noticing :)   freeall: where to begin... "Facebook Automation", "TextArea vs Input", "KeyX Events vs Changing HTML Content"... all out of scope.  everyone else - this triggers events, it doesn't type for you.

Comment: Works in Chrome 28 (so far).

Comment: The getters can simply return `k`. There's no need to attach a `keyCodeVal` property to the event object.

Comment: can someone post a non-jquery version of this? Don't need the keydown method, since it doesn't work in chrome 44.x.

Comment: That is a non-jquery version.  You can tell because there aren't any `$` and it works fine in chrome 48.  Check the jsbin link above.

Comment: I like the chromium hack

Comment: Still working in Chrome 49 on Windows 10 (unlike other "solutions" on SO). Brilliant!

Comment: On my OSX Chrome 58, `oEvent.metaKey` would always be `true` for some reason, so I had to use the `defineProperty` hack to override it to `false`, see https://gist.github.com/ejoubaud/a6667323763eeeadaa38a26ec051cb1d For my use case, I also had to dispatch the event from `document.body` instead of `document`

Answer (score 14):

Orwellophile's solution does work.

- First: 'keyCode', 'charCode' and 'which' is readonly in Safari and IE9+ (at least).
- Second: initKeyboardEvent is kind of messy. All browsers implement it in a different way. Even in webkit's there are several different implementation of initKeyboardEvent. And there is no "good"
  way to initKeyboardEvent in Opera.
- Third: initKeyboardEvent is deprecated. You need to use initKeyEvent or KeyboardEvent constructor.

Here I wrote a [cross-browser initKeyboardEvent function](https://gist.github.com/4654819) (gist):

Example:

```
var a = window.crossBrowser_initKeyboardEvent("keypress", {"key": 1, "char": "!", shiftKey: true})
alert(a.type + " | " + a.key + " | " + a.char + " | " + a.shiftKey)
```

And here is my [DOM Keyboard Event Level 3 polyfill](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill) with cross-browser KeyboardEvent constructor.

Example:

```
var a = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {"key": 1, "char": "!", shiftKey: true})
alert(a.type + " | " + a.key + " | " + a.char + " | " + a.shiftKey)
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/termi/yjc5F/)

[Example 3](http://h123.ru/-/tests/KeyboardEvent/)

Important Note 1: charCode, keyCode and which properties is deprecated. So neither my crossBrowser_initKeyboardEvent no KeyboardEvent constructor is absolutely guaranteed right values of that properties in some browsers. You can using properties "key" and "char" instead or edit my [gist](https://gist.github.com/4654819) to force using initEvent in browsers with read-only charCode, keyCode and which properties.

Important Note 2: keypress event is deprecated and for now unsupported in my [Keyboard Event Level 3 polyfill](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill). That's mean that key and char properties in keypress event can have random values. I am working to fix that problem to backward compatibility.

Comment: Best description of the problem I've seen so far. +1

Comment: @termi, I have tried to use your source to simulate event on Chrome 36, but does not work !!

Comment: @AkashKava, do you try "cross-browser initKeyboardEvent function (gist)" or polyfill? Polyfill is out-of-date. I don't have much free time to fix it. But "cross-browser initKeyboardEvent function (gist)" is working for me. Can you provide an example?

Comment: great stuff, @termi! if you have a chance, plz see if you can solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298753/how-to-send-f11-to-chrome-with-javascript-to-switch-to-fullscreen

Answer (score 4):

In order to get @Orwellophile's script to work on Google Chrome 26.0.1410.65 (on Mac OS X 10.7.5, if that matters), I had to change one line: his script appears to have the paramaters of `initKeyboardEvent` in different order than the [MDN documentation for initKeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent#initKeyboardEvent%28%29).

The changed line looks like this:

```
oEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView, k, k, "", "", false, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Well the above solutions did work, also thanks to @dland for the parameter tip. Here is something I found useful, if you are not able to get the events firing at the right place.

The @Orwellophile's script fires the event on document. It may be possible that the event listener is not always registered on `document`. I changed the last line to following and now it pretty much works every time.

`document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(oEvent);`

The `document.activeElement` always fires the event on the element where the user is currently focusing on.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of SO.  If you have a suggestion, put it in the comment to the answer.  If you have a change, then modify the code.  If you don't have the permissions to do these things, then you should most definitely not be posting your experiences and one-line changes as "Answers."

Now, it may very well be that what you say is correct, but this piece of code has been online and heavily referenced since 2012, almost 5 years ago.  From the amount of people who have used this, and commented on it, I know it works.

If I make this edge-case change now, what then?

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions above are working, but I've found one case they won't.

If Dart is being used, Dart code that uses KeyboardEvents won't work on a general Event.

You'll get something like get$keyCode is undefined.

after banging my head for hours on this, I've found the following trick:

```
function __triggerKeyboardEvent(el, keyCode)
{
   var eventObj = document.createEventObject ?
       document.createEventObject() : document.createEvent("Events");

   var tempKeyboardObj = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvents");

   if(eventObj.initEvent){
      eventObj.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
   }
   eventObj.___dart_dispatch_record_ZxYxX_0_ = tempKeyboardObj.___dart_dispatch_record_ZxYxX_0_
   eventObj.keyCode = keyCode;
   eventObj.which = keyCode;

   el.dispatchEvent ? el.dispatchEvent(eventObj) : el.fireEvent("onkeydown", eventObj);

}
```

Fooling Dart interceptor to thing our Event is actually a KeyboardEvent, did the trick.

Leaving it here, for the poor guy that is trying to test Dart app on a webkit based browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to get it to work for me, but I found why in this thread, apparently it is no longer allowed for security reasons, some events are not reliable

[JavaScript trigger an InputEvent.isTrusted = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518959/javascript-trigger-an-inputevent-istrusted-true)