# Basic example of initKeyboardEvent

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to find a basic example of the use of `initKeyboardEvent()`. Ideally, I want to create a keyboard event where when the <kbd>enter</kbd> button is pressed when a user is typing in one input field, another input field will be shown using jQuery. Does anyone know where I can find a basic understandable example of using `initKeyboardEvent()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*initKeyboardEvent* was originallly *initKeyEvent*, there is a working example at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.initKeyEvent and here: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents.

I'm sure you can find many examples through a web search: "javascript initkeyevent" and "javascript initKeyboardEvent". Likely you will need to test for support to determine which to use.

Note also that *initKeyboardEvent* will be deprecated in [DOM 4 (draft)](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/) in favour of Event constructor syntax, suggested in [DOM 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#idl-interface-KeyboardEvent-initializers) and implemented in [DOM 4 (draft)](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-event).

A simple feature test might be something like:

```
// Test for Event constructor
if (typeof Event != 'undefined') {
  var x, evt;
  try {
    x = new Event('keyboardEvent');
  } catch(e) {
    x = void 0;
  }
}

// test to see which method to use
if (typeof x != 'undefined') {
  alert('Use Event constructor');

} else if (document.createEvent) {
  evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

  if (evt && evt.initKeyboardEvent) {
    alert('Use initKeyboardEvent');

  } else if (evt && evt.initKeyEvent) {
    alert('Use initKeyEvent');
  }
}
```

But for the time being it will likely be best to test for and use DOM 2 *createEvent* with *initKeyEvent* or *initKeyboardEvent* as appropriate.

Note that Firefox 14 doesn't seem to support *initKeyboardEvent* but does support the *Event* constructor and *initKeyEvent*, IE 9 is the opposite and doesn't support *initKeyEvent* or the *Event* constructor, but does support *initKeyboardEvent*.

Answer (score 4):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561303/1587897)

In short:

Here [Cross-browser initKeyboardEvent](https://gist.github.com/4654819/)

Here [Keyboard Event Level 3 polyfill](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill)

Example:

```
var a = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {"key": 1, "char": "!", shiftKey: true})
alert(a.type + " | " + a.key + " | " + a.char + " | " + a.shiftKey)
```