# How to emulate ESC keypress on a webpage by javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

How to emulate ESC keypress on a webpage by javascript?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate left and right arrow key event with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516600/simulate-left-and-right-arrow-key-event-with-javascript)

Comment: This answer to [Working with initKeyboardEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857524/working-with-initkeyboardevent/11857825#11857825) may help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Without jQuery:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode;
function checkKeycode(e) {
var keycode;
  if (window.event) {
    keycode = window.event.keyCode;
  }
  else if (e) {
    keycode = e.which;
  }
  // enter
  if (keycode == 13) {

  }

  // escape
  if (keycode == 27) {
    //place your action here
  }
}
```

Comment: That's detecting when the esc key was pressed, it does not simulate it.

Answer (score 3):

Simulate `Esc` key using Javascript (Tested in Firefox and Chromium):

```js
window.dispatchEvent(
            new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
              altKey: false,
              code: "Escape",
              ctrlKey: false,
              isComposing: false,
              key: "Escape",
              location: 0,
              metaKey: false,
              repeat: false,
              shiftKey: false,
              which: 27,
              charCode: 0,
              keyCode: 27,
            })
          );
```

To find correct values of any key:

1. paste below to dev tools:

```js
document.addEventListener(
              "keydown",
              (e)=>{console.log(e)}
            );
```

2. Press the desired key.
3. copy values from logs.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 2):

As there is no answer to the question, here is a possible solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627860/onclick-element-simulate-esc-key).

```
function invokeEscKey() {
    var ev = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    ev.initKeyEvent(
        'keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 27, 0);
    document.body.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Note that `initKeyEvent()` is deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like this

```
$(document).delegate('input','keypress', function(e){
    code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(code=== 27){
        alert('esc pressed');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's detecting when the esc key was pressed, it does not emulate it.