# Javascript native code function gives me "foo is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, input

I'm trying to emulate keyboard key presses in the **Ekioh** SVG browser. It only supports the deprecated initKeyboardEvent event constructor.

Here is my code for creating the event:

```
evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
console.log(evt.initKeyboardEvent.toString());

// output:
// evt.initKeyboardEvent:function initKeyboardEvent() {
//     [native code]
// }

evt.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, window,
              0, keyCode, false, "", 0);

// output:
// TypeError: evt.initKeyboardEvent is not a function at file:/foo.js:302
```

How come it gets printed as a function but I can't call it?

Comment: Since it's a native function, maybe it does require to be called with the right signature?

Comment: What do you mean and how do I do that? :)

Comment: Take a look at [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and fix the parameters you are giving to this function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857524/working-with-initkeyboardevent

Comment: I mean that the error message might be misleading; the (js) function actually exists but whinges about the argument types being "wrong" so that it doesn't find the native interface with the matching signature.