# Trigger native keyboard events from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Facebook have textarea's where they expand/shrink to the size of the text inside of it. In my Chrome extension I change the text inside a textarea to be over several lines. However, the textareas expand/shrink method only works on keyboard events, so I have to trigger one.

```
var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

event.initEvent('keyup', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 38, 38);
this.dispatchEvent(event); // this is the textarea
```

(It does this for all of keyup, keydown, keypress)

But this doesn't work. Now, I know a bit of why it doesn't work, but not how to solve it. I have attached a handler to the element to see what is going on:

```
$('[role=dialog] .MessagingComposerForm textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

When the Chrome extension triggers its keyup event, the object which I can see in my console is a normal Event object, except for two things: keyCode=0 and view=null.

When I trigger the keyup event by hitting a key on my keyboard I can see that keyCode=38 and view=Window.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

ADDED:

I discovered something. If I `console.log` the event before it is dispatched it still doesn't contain the correct information. Here:

```
var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

event.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 65, 65);
event.keyCode = 65;
event.which = 65;
event.charCode = 65;

console.log(event);

this.dispatchEvent(event); // this is the textarea
```

outputs this object:

```
KeyboardEvent: {
    ...
    charCode: 0,
    keyCode: 0,
    view: Window,
    which: 0
}
```

Comment: I have made it work for mouse events. So I can easily trigger on click on elements which Facebooks handler then catches. I just can't make it work for keyboard events.

Comment: have you tried to use `initKeyboardEvent` with the same arguments instead of `initEvent` ?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript

Comment: @haynar oddly enough, now the view is set to Window. But the keyCode is still wrong. Investigates more.

Comment: Note that my "related" link is actually `keypress` on Safari. It probably won't solve your issue, but may contain some useful information.

Comment: @apsillers I read through it. And I tried a few other things. But nothing that changed anything. The jQuery examples won't work since it doesn't trigger the native handlers on the DOM elements. I think that one of the reason this is "strange" might be that it runs as a Chrome extension and may have different permissions or something similar.

Comment: I guess the keyCode is 0 because you are passing 6th argument false, you should pass the keyCode of the char which you want to trigger, see on the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent#initKeyboardEvent())

Comment: @haynar The sixth argument is a string, and it sets only the `keyIdentifier` property (at least that's what it does in Chrome). I have no idea what that property is used for.

Comment: then maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key) will help you?

Comment: I have updated the question to include something I discovered by console.log the event before it's dispatched.

Comment: I saw that, but as I understood from the post mentioned in previous comment you should use something like `Object.defineProperty()` to ake it work, it is some kind of hack

Comment: @haynar Strange behavior here. When I use defineProperty I can actually make the console.logged object look correct, but for some reason it's still not fired. (Just as a side note, I use setTimeout to make sure that the elements are actually focussed and all that).

Comment: @apsillers That's also what I noticed with the 6th argument. It was reflected in the KeyboardEvent, but keyIdentifier didn't seem to change anything in the end result.

Comment: really strange... actually I don't know what is the problem, maybe some kind of Chromium bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735

30char