# How to simulate keystrokes in a browser to control cross-domain iframe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I am particularly interested in simulating arrow keys.

Although there are many ways to simulate keys, like in this
[Keydown Simulation in Chrome fires normally but not the correct key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key)

It doesn't work if it is on a iframe

Comment: And it doesn't work on an iframe for a reason...

Comment: I don't think this can be done. [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) will prevent you from injecting events in the first place.

Comment: If you don't provide us with feedback, it is very hard for people providing answers like me to know if you resolved the situation or are still having problems. What's up?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the following scenario.

- Bob is surfing the internet and goes to your site.
- Eve's site opens an iframe with content from http://bobsbank.com
- Eve's site stars injecting keystrokes and clicks to that site, sending all of Bob's money to Eve's account

This sort of scenario is why what you're trying to do is impossible.

The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) will prevent it.

Comment: +1, exactly my point. This kind of attack can't be prevented with typical CSRF counter-measures (in fact, afaik, all the CSRF counter-measures are actually based on inability of the container frame to modify the contents of the containee).

Comment: @raina77ow Correct :) Worth mentioning that you can't really simulate keystrokes in the same domain, or even in your own page with JavaScript, only predict what they attempt to do and act accordingly, as the DOM Events model considers them to be "untrusted events" (since they are not the result of user interaction directly). http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events

Answer (score 0):

if you can modify the html from the page in the iframe you can use this what is called cross document messaging. http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging
you would fire an event from the top frame and the iframe page would recive the event and interpret the outpout and fire an event (ie key stroke inside your frame).

If you are looking for this to work on older browsers there is a jquery pluing that will work with newer and older browsers: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/