# 'onkeydown' attribute visible but null?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, event-handling, reactjs

I'm writing a Chrome extension and I'm trying to programmatically trigger a keypress event on the `textarea` element where you type in Facebook chat.

If I look at the element in the inspector, I can see that it has an `onkeydown` handler set:

```
onkeydown="run_with(this, ["legacy:control-textarea"], function() {TextAreaControl.getInstance(this)});"
```

--but I can't trigger it. While trying to figure out why I can't trigger it, I found that when I select the element using one of the classes on it and type `document.querySelector('._552m').onkeydown` in the console, it comes up `null`. Likewise, using `getAttribute` on it for `onkeydown` comes up `null`.

What am I missing here? How can I get at this event handler? Why can I see it set on the element in the inspector and yet not access it programmatically in the usual way? Is React pulling some weird magic here?

Edit: `document.querySelector('._552m').attributes` shows the `onkeydown` attribute listed....wtf...

Comment: How is your code trying to trigger it?

Comment: Both $.Event with $(elem).trigger(jQueryEvent) and elem.dispatchEvent with a native event are unsuccessful.

Comment: I'm not sure that those jQuery functions will trigger anything but jQuery event listeners. Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key

Answer (score 0):

If `document.querySelector('._552m').attributes` displays the `onkeydown` attribute, you should be able to access the event handler using `document.querySelector('._552m').getAttribute('onkeydown')` (it works for me, returns this on my facebook page):

```
"run_with(this, ["legacy:control-textarea"], function() {TextAreaControl.getInstance(this)});"
```

Otherwise, since the attributes object is just a [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) you can just access it using `getNamedItem('onkeydown')` on `document.querySelector('._552m').attributes` like this:

```
var elm = document.querySelector('._552m')
elm.attributes.getNamedItem('onkeydown')    //returns the attr itself
elm.attributes.getNamedItem('onkeydown').value   //returns the string value
```