# Microsoft Edge - Unable to set keyCode for KeyboardEvent (synthetic)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, keyboard-events

I am trying to fire `keydown` event using synthetic `new KeyboardEvent()` on Microsoft Edge (not IE) browser but not able to set `keyCode` property.
Actually, I want to simulate down arrow `keydown` event.

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
          code : 'Down',
          key: 'Down',
          keyCode: 40,
        } as KeyboardEventInit));
```

but when I dispatch this event and logs the output event, the `keyCode` property always returns to be 0 instead of 40.

The above code **works** on **Chrome**, **Firefox**, and **Safari**.
Correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Behavior confirmed.

Comment: You can try experiments with initEvent(). See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn905219(v=vs.71), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003774/simulate-enter-in-javascript.

Comment: looks like this issue only occurs with (synthetic) Keyboard event. I made a test with JS code and it is working fine with MS Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Regard [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) KeyboadrEvent constructor compatibility is unknown for EDGE.