# Triggering Synthetic Event in React App

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, events, reactjs

I'm writing a Chrome extension for Facebook and want to programmatically trigger the submission of the focused comment draft on a post. The default behavior is to submit when the user hits the Enter key, so I'm attempting to trick the Facebook UI into thinking that the user did so.

Facebook uses React and a `contenteditable` div for comment forms.

Here's a set of things that I've tried:

1) jQuery Event triggering `$('<the contenteditable div>').trigger($.Event('keydown', {which: 13}))`

- I've tried this from both the content-script environment and the actual page environment (via both an injected script that responds to `postMessage` and the Chrome console)
- I've also tried triggering the event on the `document`, from each context.
- Nothing seems to happen.

2) Same thing, but with VanillaJS event triggering. [relevant StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

- also from both environments
- Nothing happens

3) At this point I realized that this is React and it uses it's own `SyntheticEvents`, so I basically copy/pasted the [`Simulate` function from `ReactTestUtils`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/test/ReactTestUtils.js?source=c#L436) that's supposed to help testing by simulating events and ran that within the page's environment (grabbing references to the `required` objects via Facebook's frontend `require` function).

- Also does not work. The function executes fully and without errors, but there's no response from the application.

I've tried this with mostly `keydown` events, because that has the most listeners attached to it.

I'm aware of these questions, but they haven't helped my understanding: [Force React to fire event through injected JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145747/force-react-to-fire-event-through-injected-javascript)

Comment: Are you trying to get the content of the editable div to change from the keyboard events? Could you share a JSFiddle showing your problem?

Comment: Hi Matt! Did you find a way to trigger events in a way that React listens to?

Comment: I haven't, sorry! I ended up abandoning this direction and going with as lightly different solution (requiring the user to ctrl/cmd-enter, which facebook interprets as "enter" but to which my extension can have it's own handler for; see https://github.com/Shrugs/EMP/blob/master/app/scripts/contentscript.js for more info)

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear based on your description whether or not this is an issue, but `SyntheticEvent` has caused me pain before due to the fact that the object is reused. There's a note in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) about this:

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

If you aren't immediately using the event, or if you are trying to pass it into a new scope, you'll need to `persist()` it.

Comment: updated: "As of v17, e.persist() doesn’t do anything because the SyntheticEvent is no longer pooled."