# Pure Javascript - Simulate key press Chrome 53

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, keyboard-events

I asked a similar question but it seems maybe I did not get what I really need.

The last question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064517/javascript-simulate-key-events-on-chrome-53)

**My goal:**

I am writing a record and replay Chrome extension, I have recorded user`s keyboard press and now I need to replay it.

I have a list of keyCodes:

```
[42, 43, 0, 11...]
```

I need to simulate a keyboard press for each one on the `document.activeelement`
* If regular char - add it to the input \ textarea value, if backspace delete prev char, if delete - delete next char, if arrows - move the selector right \ left and etc.. (I expect normal behavior as I would press the same key)

As I mentioned in the last question - I tried many options and I added code samples. but it seems I am not understanding yet what I am really need to do for that result.

Comment: Why not use jquery?

Comment: It is a third party extension. I don`t want to load jquery on different version to the website.
I wrote the whole extention with pure JS so far and I want to finish it that way..

Comment: IIRC even if you generate these events Chrome knows they're not a real user input so doesn't modify text etc (although handlers do fire). You will need to look at the caret/selection and do string manipulation as well as fire the event

Comment: Is that mean I will have to map all the options? and write a switch case for that? sounds teribble

Comment: look at what jquery does. this question is duplicate of your other one.