# Cannot insert text simulating a keyboard keydown event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, keyboard-events

I've created a function to programmatically send a KEYDOWN event.

If I open the developer console I can see that the event is successfully dispatch.
I catch the event using this function:

```
document.addEventListener ('keydown', function () {
     console.log (JSON.stringify (event.keyCode))
}, false);
```

But if I click on an input text field and I programatically send the key value (for example) of the letter "W", the letter does not appear in it.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the function to programmatically dispatch the event:

```
function sendKeyDownEvent (keyCode) {
     var e = new Event ("keydown");
     e.keyCode = keyCode;
     e.which = e.keyCode;
     e.altKey = false;
     e.ctrlKey = true;
     e.shiftKey = false;
     e.metaKey = false;
     e.bubbles = true;
     document.dispatchEvent (e);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keydown Simulation in Chrome fires normally but not the correct key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener ('keydown', function (event) { // pass the event 
 console.log (JSON.stringify (event.keyCode))
}, false);
```

You need to get access to the event so include the variable event within the function header

Comment: _If I open the developer console I can see that the event is successfully dispatched_ - the window.event is available to many browsers without being specifically passed to the function

Comment: @mplungjan I'm able to print the event.keyCode. My problem is that the event that I dispatch doesn't write the letter in the input text field. I'm sending the keycode 89(letter W) and I want it to be written in a text input field. But it's not happening.