# Javascript/HTML Element - additional documentation - isTrusted- where to find

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I just ran into a problem. I wanted to write a small script that wrote into an input field by simulating key presses. But it doesn't work.

```html
<input type="text" id="mainInput" />
```

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById("mainInput");

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  const newEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
      charCode: 115,
      key: "s",
      which: 115
  });
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
}
```

I also attached an event listener and could confirm that my event is triggered correctly. I assume it is because the `isTrusted` flag is `false` and I understand that I cannot change that when I create an event via javascript.

But I skimmed now twice over the documetation of the input and text input field on MDN. In it has no mention of that. Because of that I cannot be sure if it really is the `isTrusted` flag or if I do something wrong. I am pretty convinced of it, but that's still different from having definite confirmation.

So, my question is two-fold:
1. Is it the `isTrusted` flag why it isn't working?
2. Where could I have read about it? Did I overlook it on MDN? Or is it hidden in some obscure RFC?

Comment: "*I could confirm that my event is triggered correctly.*" - then what does not work?

Comment: The input field remains empty in spite the correctly fired event.

Comment: I think firing the `keypress` event and adjusting the `.value` of the input are two separate things the browser does.

Comment: Yeah, of course I could have adjusted the value. But that would not have fulfilled the goal condition, which was to simulate key input. I suppose it is how the browser does it. But supposedly with the isTrusted flag

Comment: No, I don't think it has anything to do with `isTrusted`. That's just a convenience for listeners. From https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/event-istrusted/: "*This property is intended primarily for use by browser extensions, to determine if an event was dispatched by a script running in the main world or not.*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript trigger an InputEvent.isTrusted = true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49518959/1048572). It's not the event that causes the `.value` to change. It's the user input that both triggers the event *and* changes the `.value`.