# KeyboardEvent Typescript incorrect key initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, keycode

I'm trying to create an event of type **KeyboardEvent** in typescript

```
const arrowLeft = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'ArrowLeft' });
console.log(arrowLeft.keyCode, arrowLeft.key, arrowLeft.code);
```

I expect to see **arrowLeft.keyCode** to be 37 but instead I get `0, 'Left', ''` as a response. In the meanwhile I cannot change arrowLeft and set the keyCode manually because it's readonly in the KeyboardEvent interface.

Anybody has any idea if that is a Typescript issue? And how can I create an event with 37 as **keycode**? I'm trying to achieve a test on an Angular Component.

Comment: Try passing code as an argument like this: `{ key: 'ArrowLeft' ,code :37}`. And it's not a typescript issue all the properties KeyboardEvent has is read-only.

Comment: I know about this, the problem is that code is not supported in IE 11 and IE 9. There I have issues. Our implementation uses keyCode so my test should pass a KeyboardEvent as an argument with keycode 37. So I still think it's a typescript issue. Check here the compatibility https://caniuse.com/#search=Event.code

Comment: You may find a solution in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10455626/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

I still think that this is a bug from the Typescript's side because of the initializer LanguageEvent has. In any case, a workaround that worked for me was to use Object.define to set the keyCode.

```
Object.defineProperty(arrowRight, 'keyCode', {
    get : () => 39
});

console.log(arrowRight.keyCode, arrowRight.key, arrowRight.code);
```

No matter the fact that the keyCode is deprecated, that doesn't mean that the initializer shouldn't support it. The most strong argument is the fact that Internet Explorer 9 and 11 depends on that and they don't support the code https://caniuse.com/#search=event.code or fully support the key https://caniuse.com/#search=event.key So I think that LanguageEvent should allow keyCode in its initializer.

`let arrowRight = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode: 39 });`