# Is there a way to bound hotkey to trigger a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to write a extension to allow Facebook users to like a post while hovering their mouse on top of the post and pressing "L" key. I had success previously with other websites when the "like" is created as a button but apparently Facebook created the "like" as an "a link."

In this cast, jQuery's .click() command fails to trigger the actual click. Is there an alternative to this?

The code I am using is:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 108) {
    $('.x72:hover .UFILikeLink').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Like button is rendered inside of iframe, so you are out of luck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use hover click because Facebook has a comment section where the keypress will be recorded while you are typing comments - but if you are using some rare keystrokes it may be fine.

Additionally, the like button on Facebook is achieve by the span in the a tag, not the a tag itself, so the code you need is:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 108) {
    $('._4-u2:hover .UFILikeLink span').click();
  }
});
```

Now, if you do need to click the a tag in the future here are the codes you need:

First, generate fake browser click:

```
;(function( $, undefined ) {

var rkeyEvent = /^key/,
  rmouseEvent = /^(?:mouse|contextmenu)|click/;

$.fn.simulate = function( type, options ) {
  return this.each(function() {
    new $.simulate( this, type, options );
  });
};

$.simulate = function( elem, type, options ) {
  var method = $.camelCase( "simulate-" + type );

  this.target = elem;
  this.options = options;

  if ( this[ method ] ) {
    this[ method ]();
  } else {
    this.simulateEvent( elem, type, options );
  }
};

$.extend( $.simulate, {

  keyCode: {
    BACKSPACE: 8,
    COMMA: 188,
    DELETE: 46,
    DOWN: 40,
    END: 35,
    ENTER: 13,
    ESCAPE: 27,
    HOME: 36,
    LEFT: 37,
    NUMPAD_ADD: 107,
    NUMPAD_DECIMAL: 110,
    NUMPAD_DIVIDE: 111,
    NUMPAD_ENTER: 108,
    NUMPAD_MULTIPLY: 106,
    NUMPAD_SUBTRACT: 109,
    PAGE_DOWN: 34,
    PAGE_UP: 33,
    PERIOD: 190,
    RIGHT: 39,
    SPACE: 32,
    TAB: 9,
    UP: 38
  },

  buttonCode: {
    LEFT: 0,
    MIDDLE: 1,
    RIGHT: 2
  }
});

$.extend( $.simulate.prototype, {

  simulateEvent: function( elem, type, options ) {
    var event = this.createEvent( type, options );
    this.dispatchEvent( elem, type, event, options );
  },

  createEvent: function( type, options ) {
    if ( rkeyEvent.test( type ) ) {
      return this.keyEvent( type, options );
    }

    if ( rmouseEvent.test( type ) ) {
      return this.mouseEvent( type, options );
    }
  },

  mouseEvent: function( type, options ) {
    var event, eventDoc, doc, body;
    options = $.extend({
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: (type !== "mousemove"),
      view: window,
      detail: 0,
      screenX: 0,
      screenY: 0,
      clientX: 1,
      clientY: 1,
      ctrlKey: false,
      altKey: false,
      shiftKey: false,
      metaKey: false,
      button: 0,
      relatedTarget: undefined
    }, options );

    if ( document.createEvent ) {
      event = document.createEvent( "MouseEvents" );
      event.initMouseEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable,
        options.view, options.detail,
        options.screenX, options.screenY, options.clientX, options.clientY,
        options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey,
        options.button, options.relatedTarget || document.body.parentNode );

      // IE 9+ creates events with pageX and pageY set to 0.
      // Trying to modify the properties throws an error,
      // so we define getters to return the correct values.
      if ( event.pageX === 0 && event.pageY === 0 && Object.defineProperty ) {
        eventDoc = event.relatedTarget.ownerDocument || document;
        doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
        body = eventDoc.body;

        Object.defineProperty( event, "pageX", {
          get: function() {
            return options.clientX +
              ( doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0 ) -
              ( doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0 );
          }
        });
        Object.defineProperty( event, "pageY", {
          get: function() {
            return options.clientY +
              ( doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0 ) -
              ( doc && doc.clientTop || body && body.clientTop || 0 );
          }
        });
      }
    } else if ( document.createEventObject ) {
      event = document.createEventObject();
      $.extend( event, options );
      // standards event.button uses constants defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974877(v=vs.85).aspx
      // old IE event.button uses constants defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533544(v=vs.85).aspx
      // so we actually need to map the standard back to oldIE
      event.button = {
        0: 1,
        1: 4,
        2: 2
      }[ event.button ] || ( event.button === -1 ? 0 : event.button );
    }

    return event;
  },

  keyEvent: function( type, options ) {
    var event;
    options = $.extend({
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      view: window,
      ctrlKey: false,
      altKey: false,
      shiftKey: false,
      metaKey: false,
      keyCode: 0,
      charCode: undefined
    }, options );

    if ( document.createEvent ) {
      try {
        event = document.createEvent( "KeyEvents" );
        event.initKeyEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, options.view,
          options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey,
          options.keyCode, options.charCode );
      // initKeyEvent throws an exception in WebKit
      // see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406784/initkeyevent-keypress-only-works-in-firefox-need-a-cross-browser-solution
      // and also https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13368
      // fall back to a generic event until we decide to implement initKeyboardEvent
      } catch( err ) {
        event = document.createEvent( "Events" );
        event.initEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable );
        $.extend( event, {
          view: options.view,
          ctrlKey: options.ctrlKey,
          altKey: options.altKey,
          shiftKey: options.shiftKey,
          metaKey: options.metaKey,
          keyCode: options.keyCode,
          charCode: options.charCode
        });
      }
    } else if ( document.createEventObject ) {
      event = document.createEventObject();
      $.extend( event, options );
    }

    if ( !!/msie [\w.]+/.exec( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) || (({}).toString.call( window.opera ) === "[object Opera]") ) {
      event.keyCode = (options.charCode > 0) ? options.charCode : options.keyCode;
      event.charCode = undefined;
    }

    return event;
  },

  dispatchEvent: function( elem, type, event ) {
    if ( elem[ type ] ) {
      elem[ type ]();
    } else if ( elem.dispatchEvent ) {
      elem.dispatchEvent( event );
    } else if ( elem.fireEvent ) {
      elem.fireEvent( "on" + type, event );
    }
  },

  simulateFocus: function() {
    var focusinEvent,
      triggered = false,
      element = $( this.target );

    function trigger() {
      triggered = true;
    }

    element.bind( "focus", trigger );
    element[ 0 ].focus();

    if ( !triggered ) {
      focusinEvent = $.Event( "focusin" );
      focusinEvent.preventDefault();
      element.trigger( focusinEvent );
      element.triggerHandler( "focus" );
    }
    element.unbind( "focus", trigger );
  },

  simulateBlur: function() {
    var focusoutEvent,
      triggered = false,
      element = $( this.target );

    function trigger() {
      triggered = true;
    }

    element.bind( "blur", trigger );
    element[ 0 ].blur();

    // blur events are async in IE
    setTimeout(function() {
      // IE won't let the blur occur if the window is inactive
      if ( element[ 0 ].ownerDocument.activeElement === element[ 0 ] ) {
        element[ 0 ].ownerDocument.body.focus();
      }

      // Firefox won't trigger events if the window is inactive
      // IE doesn't trigger events if we had to manually focus the body
      if ( !triggered ) {
        focusoutEvent = $.Event( "focusout" );
        focusoutEvent.preventDefault();
        element.trigger( focusoutEvent );
        element.triggerHandler( "blur" );
      }
      element.unbind( "blur", trigger );
    }, 1 );
  }
});



/** complex events **/

function findCenter( elem ) {
  var offset,
    document = $( elem.ownerDocument );
  elem = $( elem );
  offset = elem.offset();

  return {
    x: offset.left + elem.outerWidth() / 2 - document.scrollLeft(),
    y: offset.top + elem.outerHeight() / 2 - document.scrollTop()
  };
}

function findCorner( elem ) {
  var offset,
    document = $( elem.ownerDocument );
  elem = $( elem );
  offset = elem.offset();

  return {
    x: offset.left - document.scrollLeft(),
    y: offset.top - document.scrollTop()
  };
}

$.extend( $.simulate.prototype, {
  simulateDrag: function() {
    var i = 0,
      target = this.target,
      eventDoc = target.ownerDocument,
      options = this.options,
      center = options.handle === "corner" ? findCorner( target ) : findCenter( target ),
      x = Math.floor( center.x ),
      y = Math.floor( center.y ),
      coord = { clientX: x, clientY: y },
      dx = options.dx || ( options.x !== undefined ? options.x - x : 0 ),
      dy = options.dy || ( options.y !== undefined ? options.y - y : 0 ),
      moves = options.moves || 3;

    this.simulateEvent( target, "mousedown", coord );

    for ( ; i < moves ; i++ ) {
      x += dx / moves;
      y += dy / moves;

      coord = {
        clientX: Math.round( x ),
        clientY: Math.round( y )
      };

      this.simulateEvent( eventDoc, "mousemove", coord );
    }

    if ( $.contains( eventDoc, target ) ) {
      this.simulateEvent( target, "mouseup", coord );
      this.simulateEvent( target, "click", coord );
    } else {
      this.simulateEvent( eventDoc, "mouseup", coord );
    }
  }
});

})( jQuery );
```

Now you can "simulate" the click by:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 108) {
    $('._4-u2:hover .UFILikeLink').simulate('click');
  }
});
```

Cheers.