# jQuery plug-in simulate only works after click to inspect the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to get the jQuery simulate plug-in to work with drag and drop. I have tried to run the below snippet in chrome dev console. It only drags the element if I right click the element and select Inspect then run the snippet. I'm guessing the element need to be focused or something ? I have tried to run the below snippet on the website (http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Thanks in advance !

```
 /*!
 * jQuery Simulate v1.0.0 - simulate browser mouse and keyboard events
 * https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate
 *
 * Copyright 2012 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2014-08-22
 */

;(function( $, undefined ) {

var rkeyEvent = /^key/,
    rmouseEvent = /^(?:mouse|contextmenu)|click/;

$.fn.simulate = function( type, options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        new $.simulate( this, type, options );
    });
};

$.simulate = function( elem, type, options ) {
    var method = $.camelCase( "simulate-" + type );

    this.target = elem;
    this.options = options;

    if ( this[ method ] ) {
        this[ method ]();
    } else {
        this.simulateEvent( elem, type, options );
    }
};

$.extend( $.simulate, {

    keyCode: {
        BACKSPACE: 8,
        COMMA: 188,
        DELETE: 46,
        DOWN: 40,
        END: 35,
        ENTER: 13,
        ESCAPE: 27,
        HOME: 36,
        LEFT: 37,
        NUMPAD_ADD: 107,
        NUMPAD_DECIMAL: 110,
        NUMPAD_DIVIDE: 111,
        NUMPAD_ENTER: 108,
        NUMPAD_MULTIPLY: 106,
        NUMPAD_SUBTRACT: 109,
        PAGE_DOWN: 34,
        PAGE_UP: 33,
        PERIOD: 190,
        RIGHT: 39,
        SPACE: 32,
        TAB: 9,
        UP: 38
    },

    buttonCode: {
        LEFT: 0,
        MIDDLE: 1,
        RIGHT: 2
    }
});

$.extend( $.simulate.prototype, {

    simulateEvent: function( elem, type, options ) {
        var event = this.createEvent( type, options );
        this.dispatchEvent( elem, type, event, options );
    },

    createEvent: function( type, options ) {
        if ( rkeyEvent.test( type ) ) {
            return this.keyEvent( type, options );
        }

        if ( rmouseEvent.test( type ) ) {
            return this.mouseEvent( type, options );
        }
    },

    mouseEvent: function( type, options ) {
        var event, eventDoc, doc, body;
        options = $.extend({
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: (type !== "mousemove"),
            view: window,
            detail: 0,
            screenX: 0,
            screenY: 0,
            clientX: 1,
            clientY: 1,
            ctrlKey: false,
            altKey: false,
            shiftKey: false,
            metaKey: false,
            button: 0,
            relatedTarget: undefined
        }, options );

        if ( document.createEvent ) {
            event = document.createEvent( "MouseEvents" );
            event.initMouseEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable,
                options.view, options.detail,
                options.screenX, options.screenY, options.clientX, options.clientY,
                options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey,
                options.button, options.relatedTarget || document.body.parentNode );

            // IE 9+ creates events with pageX and pageY set to 0.
            // Trying to modify the properties throws an error,
            // so we define getters to return the correct values.
            if ( event.pageX === 0 && event.pageY === 0 && Object.defineProperty ) {
                eventDoc = event.relatedTarget.ownerDocument || document;
                doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
                body = eventDoc.body;

                Object.defineProperty( event, "pageX", {
                    get: function() {
                        return options.clientX +
                            ( doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0 ) -
                            ( doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0 );
                    }
                });
                Object.defineProperty( event, "pageY", {
                    get: function() {
                        return options.clientY +
                            ( doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0 ) -
                            ( doc && doc.clientTop || body && body.clientTop || 0 );
                    }
                });
            }
        } else if ( document.createEventObject ) {
            event = document.createEventObject();
            $.extend( event, options );
            // standards event.button uses constants defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974877(v=vs.85).aspx
            // old IE event.button uses constants defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533544(v=vs.85).aspx
            // so we actually need to map the standard back to oldIE
            event.button = {
                0: 1,
                1: 4,
                2: 2
            }[ event.button ] || ( event.button === -1 ? 0 : event.button );
        }

        return event;
    },

    keyEvent: function( type, options ) {
        var event;
        options = $.extend({
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window,
            ctrlKey: false,
            altKey: false,
            shiftKey: false,
            metaKey: false,
            keyCode: 0,
            charCode: undefined
        }, options );

        if ( document.createEvent ) {
            try {
                event = document.createEvent( "KeyEvents" );
                event.initKeyEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, options.view,
                    options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey,
                    options.keyCode, options.charCode );
            // initKeyEvent throws an exception in WebKit
            // see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406784/initkeyevent-keypress-only-works-in-firefox-need-a-cross-browser-solution
            // and also https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13368
            // fall back to a generic event until we decide to implement initKeyboardEvent
            } catch( err ) {
                event = document.createEvent( "Events" );
                event.initEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable );
                $.extend( event, {
                    view: options.view,
                    ctrlKey: options.ctrlKey,
                    altKey: options.altKey,
                    shiftKey: options.shiftKey,
                    metaKey: options.metaKey,
                    keyCode: options.keyCode,
                    charCode: options.charCode
                });
            }
        } else if ( document.createEventObject ) {
            event = document.createEventObject();
            $.extend( event, options );
        }

        if ( !!/msie [\w.]+/.exec( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) || (({}).toString.call( window.opera ) === "[object Opera]") ) {
            event.keyCode = (options.charCode > 0) ? options.charCode : options.keyCode;
            event.charCode = undefined;
        }

        return event;
    },

    dispatchEvent: function( elem, type, event ) {
        if ( elem[ type ] ) {
            elem[ type ]();
        } else if ( elem.dispatchEvent ) {
            elem.dispatchEvent( event );
        } else if ( elem.fireEvent ) {
            elem.fireEvent( "on" + type, event );
        }
    },

    simulateFocus: function() {
        var focusinEvent,
            triggered = false,
            element = $( this.target );

        function trigger() {
            triggered = true;
        }

        element.bind( "focus", trigger );
        element[ 0 ].focus();

        if ( !triggered ) {
            focusinEvent = $.Event( "focusin" );
            focusinEvent.preventDefault();
            element.trigger( focusinEvent );
            element.triggerHandler( "focus" );
        }
        element.unbind( "focus", trigger );
    },

    simulateBlur: function() {
        var focusoutEvent,
            triggered = false,
            element = $( this.target );

        function trigger() {
            triggered = true;
        }

        element.bind( "blur", trigger );
        element[ 0 ].blur();

        // blur events are async in IE
        setTimeout(function() {
            // IE won't let the blur occur if the window is inactive
            if ( element[ 0 ].ownerDocument.activeElement === element[ 0 ] ) {
                element[ 0 ].ownerDocument.body.focus();
            }

            // Firefox won't trigger events if the window is inactive
            // IE doesn't trigger events if we had to manually focus the body
            if ( !triggered ) {
                focusoutEvent = $.Event( "focusout" );
                focusoutEvent.preventDefault();
                element.trigger( focusoutEvent );
                element.triggerHandler( "blur" );
            }
            element.unbind( "blur", trigger );
        }, 1 );
    }
});



/** complex events **/

function findCenter( elem ) {
    var offset,
        document = $( elem.ownerDocument );
    elem = $( elem );
    offset = elem.offset();

    return {
        x: offset.left + elem.outerWidth() / 2 - document.scrollLeft(),
        y: offset.top + elem.outerHeight() / 2 - document.scrollTop()
    };
}

function findCorner( elem ) {
    var offset,
        document = $( elem.ownerDocument );
    elem = $( elem );
    offset = elem.offset();

    return {
        x: offset.left - document.scrollLeft(),
        y: offset.top - document.scrollTop()
    };
}

$.extend( $.simulate.prototype, {
    simulateDrag: function() {
        var i = 0,
            target = this.target,
            options = this.options,
            center = options.handle === "corner" ? findCorner( target ) : findCenter( target ),
            x = Math.floor( center.x ),
            y = Math.floor( center.y ),
            coord = { clientX: x, clientY: y },
            dx = options.dx || ( options.x !== undefined ? options.x - x : 0 ),
            dy = options.dy || ( options.y !== undefined ? options.y - y : 0 ),
            moves = options.moves || 3;

        this.simulateEvent( target, "mousedown", coord );

        for ( ; i < moves ; i++ ) {
            x += dx / moves;
            y += dy / moves;

            coord = {
                clientX: Math.round( x ),
                clientY: Math.round( y )
            };

            this.simulateEvent( target.ownerDocument, "mousemove", coord );
        }

        if ( $.contains( document, target ) ) {
            this.simulateEvent( target, "mouseup", coord );
            this.simulateEvent( target, "click", coord );
        } else {
            this.simulateEvent( document, "mouseup", coord );
        }
    }
});

})( jQuery );

var el = $("#draggable");
el.simulate("drag", {dx: 5, dy:5});
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Giving us the entire code for the plugin is *not* minimal.

Comment: added: if I run the snippet without inspecting the element. jquery returns 'jQuery.fn.init' in the dev console. Looks like it's not able to find the web element ?