# Drag and drop is not working on Chrome 91 using Selenium WebDriver, Action Class and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, salesforce-lightning

On latest version of chrome 91, the drag and drop of elements using Selenium Action class or java script is not working. I have tried all the possible cases like using below approaches

1. Javascript method to drag and drop.

Java script method 1

```js
function customEvent(typeOfEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent, true, true, null);
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {},
        setData: function (key, value) {
            this.data[key] = value;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return this.data[key];
        }
    };
    return event;
}
function dispatchEvent(element, event, transferData) {
    if (transferData !== undefined) {
        event.dataTransfer = transferData;
    }
    if (element.dispatchEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event.type, event);
    }
}
function executeDrageAndDrop(element, target) {
    var dragStartEvent = customEvent('dragstart');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);
    var dropEvent = customEvent('drop');
    dispatchEvent(target, dropEvent, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);
    var dragEndEvent = customEvent('dragend');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent, dropEvent.dataTransfer);
}
```

Java script method 2 :

```js
function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {
var event =document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);
event.dataTransfer = {
data: {},
setData: function (key, value) {
this.data[key] = value;
},
getData: function (key) {
return this.data[key];
}
};
return event;
}

function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {
if (transferData !== undefined) {
event.dataTransfer = transferData;
}
if (element.dispatchEvent) {
element.dispatchEvent(event);
} else if (element.fireEvent) {
element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);
}
}

function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {
var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');
dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);
var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');
dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);
var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');
dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);
}

var source = arguments[0];
var destination = arguments[1];
simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);", new Object[]{source, destination}
```

2. Using jQuery method.
   JQuery

   ```js
    /*!
    * jQuery Simulate v@VERSION - simulate browser mouse and keyboard events
    * https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate
    *
    * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
    * Released under the MIT license.
    * http://jquery.org/license
    *
    * Date: @DATE
    */

   (function( $, undefined ) {

   var rkeyEvent = /^key/,
       rdashAlpha = /-([a-z])/g,
       rmouseEvent = /^(?:mouse|contextmenu)|click/;

   function fcamelCase( _all, letter ) {
       return letter.toUpperCase();
   }

   function camelCase( string ) {
       return string.replace( rdashAlpha, fcamelCase );
   }

   $.fn.simulate = function( type, options ) {
       return this.each(function() {
           new $.simulate( this, type, options );
       });
   };

   $.simulate = function( elem, type, options ) {
       var method = camelCase( "simulate-" + type );

       this.target = elem;
       this.options = options;

       if ( this[ method ] ) {
           this[ method ]();
       } else {
           this.simulateEvent( elem, type, options );
       }
   };

   $.extend( $.simulate, {

       keyCode: {
           BACKSPACE: 8,
           COMMA: 188,
           DELETE: 46,
           DOWN: 40,
           END: 35,
           ENTER: 13,
           ESCAPE: 27,
           HOME: 36,
           LEFT: 37,
           NUMPAD_ADD: 107,
           NUMPAD_DECIMAL: 110,
           NUMPAD_DIVIDE: 111,
           NUMPAD_ENTER: 108,
           NUMPAD_MULTIPLY: 106,
           NUMPAD_SUBTRACT: 109,
           PAGE_DOWN: 34,
           PAGE_UP: 33,
           PERIOD: 190,
           RIGHT: 39,
           SPACE: 32,
           TAB: 9,
           UP: 38
       },

       buttonCode: {
           LEFT: 0,
           MIDDLE: 1,
           RIGHT: 2
       }
   });

   $.extend( $.simulate.prototype, {

       simulateEvent: function( elem, type, options ) {
           var event = this.createEvent( type, options );
           this.dispatchEvent( elem, type, event, options );
       },

       createEvent: function( type, options ) {
           if ( rkeyEvent.test( type ) ) {
               return this.keyEvent( type, options );
           }

           if ( rmouseEvent.test( type ) ) {
               return this.mouseEvent( type, options );
           }
       },

       mouseEvent: function( type, options ) {
           var event, eventDoc, doc, body;
           options = $.extend({
               bubbles: true,
               cancelable: (type !== "mousemove"),
               view: window,
               detail: 0,
               screenX: 0,
               screenY: 0,
               clientX: 1,
               clientY: 1,
               ctrlKey: false,
               altKey: false,
               shiftKey: false,
               metaKey: false,
               button: 0,
               relatedTarget: undefined
           }, options );

           if ( document.createEvent ) {
               event = document.createEvent( "MouseEvents" );
               event.initMouseEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable,
                   options.view, options.detail,
                   options.screenX, options.screenY, options.clientX, options.clientY,
                   options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey,
                   options.button, options.relatedTarget || document.body.parentNode );

               // IE 9+ creates events with pageX and pageY set to 0.
               // Trying to modify the properties throws an error,
               // so we define getters to return the correct values.
               if ( event.pageX === 0 && event.pageY === 0 && Object.defineProperty ) {
                   eventDoc = event.relatedTarget.ownerDocument || document;
                   doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
                   body = eventDoc.body;

                   Object.defineProperty( event, "pageX", {
                       get: function() {
                           return options.clientX +
                               ( doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0 ) -
                               ( doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0 );
                       }
                   });
                   Object.defineProperty( event, "pageY", {
                       get: function() {
                           return options.clientY +
                               ( doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0 ) -
                               ( doc && doc.clientTop || body && body.clientTop || 0 );
                       }
                   });
               }
           } else if ( document.createEventObject ) {
               event = document.createEventObject();
               $.extend( event, options );
               // standards event.button uses constants defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974877(v=vs.85).aspx
               // old IE event.button uses constants defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533544(v=vs.85).aspx
               // so we actually need to map the standard back to oldIE
               event.button = {
                   0: 1,
                   1: 4,
                   2: 2
               }[ event.button ] || ( event.button === -1 ? 0 : event.button );
           }

           return event;
       },

       keyEvent: function( type, options ) {
           var event;
           options = $.extend({
               bubbles: true,
               cancelable: true,
               view: window,
               ctrlKey: false,
               altKey: false,
               shiftKey: false,
               metaKey: false,
               keyCode: 0,
               charCode: undefined
           }, options );

           if ( document.createEvent ) {
               try {
                   event = document.createEvent( "KeyEvents" );
                   event.initKeyEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, options.view,
                       options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey,
                       options.keyCode, options.charCode );
               // initKeyEvent throws an exception in WebKit
               // see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406784/initkeyevent-keypress-only-works-in-firefox-need-a-cross-browser-solution
               // and also https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13368
               // fall back to a generic event until we decide to implement initKeyboardEvent
               } catch( err ) {
                   event = document.createEvent( "Events" );
                   event.initEvent( type, options.bubbles, options.cancelable );
                   $.extend( event, {
                       view: options.view,
                       ctrlKey: options.ctrlKey,
                       altKey: options.altKey,
                       shiftKey: options.shiftKey,
                       metaKey: options.metaKey,
                       keyCode: options.keyCode,
                       charCode: options.charCode
                   });
               }
           } else if ( document.createEventObject ) {
               event = document.createEventObject();
               $.extend( event, options );
           }

           if ( !!/msie [\w.]+/.exec( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() ) || (({}).toString.call( window.opera ) === "[object Opera]") ) {
               event.keyCode = (options.charCode > 0) ? options.charCode : options.keyCode;
               event.charCode = undefined;
           }

           return event;
       },

       dispatchEvent: function( elem, type, event ) {
           if ( elem.dispatchEvent ) {
               elem.dispatchEvent( event );
           } else if ( type === "click" && elem.click && elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input" ) {
               elem.click();
           } else if ( elem.fireEvent ) {
               elem.fireEvent( "on" + type, event );
           }
       },

       simulateFocus: function() {
           var focusinEvent,
               triggered = false,
               element = $( this.target );

           function trigger() {
               triggered = true;
           }

           element.on( "focus", trigger );
           element[ 0 ].focus();

           if ( !triggered ) {
               focusinEvent = $.Event( "focusin" );
               focusinEvent.preventDefault();
               element.trigger( focusinEvent );
               element.triggerHandler( "focus" );
           }
           element.off( "focus", trigger );
       },

       simulateBlur: function() {
           var focusoutEvent,
               triggered = false,
               element = $( this.target );

           function trigger() {
               triggered = true;
           }

           element.on( "blur", trigger );
           element[ 0 ].blur();

           // blur events are async in IE
           setTimeout(function() {
               // IE won't let the blur occur if the window is inactive
               if ( element[ 0 ].ownerDocument.activeElement === element[ 0 ] ) {
                   element[ 0 ].ownerDocument.body.focus();
               }

               // Firefox won't trigger events if the window is inactive
               // IE doesn't trigger events if we had to manually focus the body
               if ( !triggered ) {
                   focusoutEvent = $.Event( "focusout" );
                   focusoutEvent.preventDefault();
                   element.trigger( focusoutEvent );
                   element.triggerHandler( "blur" );
               }
               element.off( "blur", trigger );
           }, 1 );
       }
   });



   /** complex events **/

   function findCenter( elem ) {
       var offset,
           document = $( elem.ownerDocument );
       elem = $( elem );
       offset = elem.offset();

       return {
           x: offset.left + elem.outerWidth() / 2 - document.scrollLeft(),
           y: offset.top + elem.outerHeight() / 2 - document.scrollTop()
       };
   }

   function findCorner( elem ) {
       var offset,
           document = $( elem.ownerDocument );
       elem = $( elem );
       offset = elem.offset();

       return {
           x: offset.left - document.scrollLeft(),
           y: offset.top - document.scrollTop()
       };
   }

   $.extend( $.simulate.prototype, {
       simulateDrag: function() {
           var i = 0,
               target = this.target,
               eventDoc = target.ownerDocument,
               options = this.options,
               center = options.handle === "corner" ? findCorner( target ) : findCenter( target ),
               x = Math.floor( center.x ),
               y = Math.floor( center.y ),
               coord = { clientX: x, clientY: y },
               dx = options.dx || ( options.x !== undefined ? options.x - x : 0 ),
               dy = options.dy || ( options.y !== undefined ? options.y - y : 0 ),
               moves = options.moves || 3;

           this.simulateEvent( target, "mousedown", coord );

           for ( ; i < moves ; i++ ) {
               x += dx / moves;
               y += dy / moves;

               coord = {
                   clientX: Math.round( x ),
                   clientY: Math.round( y )
               };

               this.simulateEvent( eventDoc, "mousemove", coord );
           }

           if ( $.contains( eventDoc, target ) ) {
               this.simulateEvent( target, "mouseup", coord );
               this.simulateEvent( target, "click", coord );
           } else {
               this.simulateEvent( eventDoc, "mouseup", coord );
           }
       }
   });

   })( jQuery );
   ```
3. Using Robot Class.

   ```
   Locatable element = (Locatable)sourceElement ;
   Point p= element.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
   int sourceX=p.getX();
   int sourceY=p.getY();

   Locatable elementTarget = (Locatable)destElement;
   Point Target= elementTarget.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
   int targetX=Target.getX();
   int targetY=Target.getY();


   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.mouseMove(sourceX, sourceY);
   robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   robot.mouseMove(targetX, targetY);
   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   ```
4. Using Selenium Touch Actions.

   ```
       TouchActions builder = new TouchActions(driver);
   builder.longPress(sourceElement).moveToElement(destElement).release(destElement).perform();
   ```

But none of the solution has worked for me. Drag and drop was working on prior chrome version 89.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBz61.jpg)

I have attached the screenshot of source & target elements which are highlighted using yellow color & red underline.

Could anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Hi @itronic1990, no i'm not getting any error

Comment: Hi @Navee_3665 were you able to resolve this issue. I have the same issue where the mouse movement off page and back to viewport was working in Chrome versions 90 and below. But it stopped working for later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with using offset I also facing same issue for mouse over click that was resolved using below code

```
    Locatable elementLocation = (Locatable)element ;
    Point p= elementLocation.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
    int sourceX=p.getX();
    int sourceY=p.getY();
    new Actions(driver).moveByOffset(sourceX, sourceY).click().build().perform();
```